# Ĉu la provinconomo "Asturio" estas landobaza aŭ gentobaza?

Tags: affixes

Ĉu la provinconomo "Asturio" estas landobaza aŭ gentobaza?

**Landobaza:**

- Provinco: Asturi·o
- Loĝanto: asturi·an·o
- Lingvo: la asturi·a

**Gentobaza:**

- Provinco: Astur·i·o / Astur·uj·o
- Loĝanto: astur·o
- Lingvo: la astur·a

La paĝo "Landoj kaj lingvoj de la mondo" de Bertilo [prezentas ĝin kiel landobazan vorton](https://bertilow.com/lanlin/notoj.html#ES).

[PIV prezentas "Asturio" kiel la bazan vorton](https://vortaro.net/#Asturio_k), do supozeble ankaŭ PIV prezentas ĝin kiel landobazan vorton.

Interrete mi trovas rezultojn kaj por "asturoj" kaj por "asturianoj".

Eble povas esti, ke ambaŭ sistemoj estas uzataj. Tiuokaze mi ŝatus scii, kiu sistemo estas plej ofta.

Answer (score 2):

Ili uzas por si mem la gentobazan formon en la nomo de la asocio [Astura Esperanta Asocio](https://carleos.epv.uniovi.es/%7Efaustino/) kaj en kelkaj artikoloj de [Astura Bukedo](https://carleos.epv.uniovi.es/%7Efaustino/abukedo/abukedo.html), ekzemple:

```
Temas pri antologio de asturaj verkistoj de la lasta jarcento.
```

kaj

```
(1853-1938) naskiĝis en Entralgo, Laviana. Li vivis en Asturio...
```

Sed vi trovos kaj gentobazajn kaj landobazajn formojn en ilia dokumentaro, eĉ en relative samtempaj tekstoj. Ekzemple [asturiano](https://carleos.epv.uniovi.es/%7Efaustino/heleco/93/heleco-93.pdf) (gazeto Heleco n. 93 de ilia asocio):

```
juna asturiano kiu, tamen, ne loĝas en nia  regiono.
```

kaj ankaŭ troveblas [asturo](https://carleos.epv.uniovi.es/%7Efaustino/heleco/95/heleco-95.pdf) (gazeto Heleco n. 95):

```
varbis siajn unuajn sekvantojn inter tiuj asturoj kiuj
```

Interese, en la himno ili uzis la nomon [Asturlando](https://carleos.epv.uniovi.es/%7Efaustino/heleco/93/heleco-93.pdf),

Laŭ mia supraĵa esploro, ŝajne la vorto `regiono` estas tiu kiun ili uzas por Asturio.

Comment: Pravas, ke la sistemo de nomoj de landoj kaj landanoj estas senkohera. Mi ne memoras, kie mi vidis sekvan proponon, sed mi rigardas ĝin bona. Uzu "-ano" ĉiam kaj nur por montri civitanecon, Do civitanoj de Hispanio estas  hispanianoj kaj Asturio estas parto de tiu lando kaj tie loĝas astur(i)oj.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas “[...] kaj tie loĝas **asturianoj**”, mi supozas. Ĉu mi miskomprenis?

Comment: @marcus, eble mi skribis malklare, sed mi celis, ke astur(i)o ĉar Asturio ne estas sendependa lando. Ne ekzistas civitaneco, ŝtataneco de Asturio.

Answer (score 1):

En la Granda Hispana-Esperanta Vortaro aperas:

> astura*, asturia | asturo*, asturiano | la astura*, la asturia
> (lingvo) | Asturio | Princo de Asturio.

La steleto indikas ke la vorto estas neoficiala aŭ speco de neologismo. La praktika lingvouzo montras ke ambaŭ formoj estas uzataj, kiel jam komentis Euduardo Trápani, sed mi ne scias kiu estas plej ofte uzata. Google donas 679 trafojn por *astura lingvo* kaj 832 por *asturia lingvo*, sed tio estas nura kuriozaĵo apenaŭ statistike signifa. Mi supozas ke la elekto dependas de kiel strikta oni celas esti kaj de persona prefero.